# JPA: How to remove unnecessary SELECT before save()?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a Entity `Student` which is `@ManyToOne` with another Entity `School`, Where `School` is pre-existing in the database and is fixed.

Entity `User`:

```java
@Data
@Entity(name = "user")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String username;

    @ManyToOne
    private School school;
}
```

Entity `School`:

```java
@Data
@Entity(name = "school")
public class School {
    @Id
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private int id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;

    private String shorten;

    @JsonProperty(value = "logo_url")
    private String logoUrl;

    private float longitude;

    private float latitude;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private boolean opened;
}
```

When adding a user, I POST the following json from Postman:

```
{
    "username": "abcd",
    "school_id": 2
}
```

Then,

```java
School school = new School();
school.setId(2);    //"school_id" above

User user = new User();
user.setUsername("abcd");
user.setSchool(school);

userRepository.save(user);
```

Because I think that to add a new `user`, only the `School` `id` is enough, and no other `School` parameters are required. But every time I run, it will run the `select` statement to select all fields of `School` by `id` before `save()`.

My question is: how to remove this unnecessary operation so that before the `save()`, there is no need to `select`? (I know that custom sql statements can be implemented, but I feel like this will break the object orientation of JPA)

Comment: The `school` you created is not known to the entity manager, so it first has to select it from the table so that it can link it to the user.

Comment: check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21233853/hibernate-dynamicupdatevalue-true-selectbeforeupdatevalue-true-performance

Answer (score 2):

use below annotation on entity class

```
@SelectBeforeUpdate(value=false)
```

Comment: on which entity class? User or School?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `getReference` method to avoid this issue

```
School school = entityManager.getReference(School.class, 2);
```

If you are using Spring Data JPA, this method is exposed as `getOne` on the repository.

See [How do find and getReference EntityManager methods work when using JPA and Hibernate](https://vladmihalcea.com/entitymanager-find-getreference-jpa/)